# Ruby Bundler - Multiple Ruby versions in the same gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using `rbenv` and `bundler` on macos.

I need to maintain multiple versions of Ruby for my application. Specifically 2.2.4 and 2.5.5. Different users will have different versions.

Currently I am only working with 2.2.4 so I do the following. My `gemfile` looks like this

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '2.2.4'

gem "net-ssh", "4.1.0"
gem "net-scp", "2.0.0"
.....
```

To install I run `bundle install` and then to deploy with my application I run

```
bundle install --deployment --path src/mct-tools/ext/gems
```

This generates a folder `src/mct-tools/ext/gems/ruby/2.2.0` in my application that I then distribute.

Now I would like to add ruby 2.5.5 with updated gems so I was wondering whether it would be acceptable to have a gemfile looking like this one

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '2.2.4'

gem "net-ssh", "4.1.0"
gem "net-scp", "2.0.0"
.....

ruby '2.5.5'

gem "net-ssh", "6.1.0"
gem "net-scp", "3.0.0"
.....
```

so that when I deploy with `bundle install --deployment --path src/mct-tools/ext/gems` the two versions are added to the gems folder.

Is this the correct approach? An alternative would be to specify two different gemfiles for each version and then switch between them.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds snide, but... *Why??* You should expect users of your application to install a well-defined list of dependencies. If one client has an older version of the application that's not been updated in a long time, then that's annoying but fine - they can catch up at a later date and install all the new dependancies.

Comment: Trying to simultaneously support multiple versions of a language, along with all the other dependencies, is going to lead you down a path of madness.

Comment: In theory you are right. However I am using Ruby to write plugins for a different software (SketchUp if you are curious). Different versions of SketchUp support different versions of Ruby. Some customers do not want to update their software because it is expensive or some other reason. The most updated version of Ruby simply would not work in the previous version of the software. If I want to support them I need to handle different versions.

Comment: @TomLord My hope is that at some point everyone will update so I can get rid of old version.

Comment: You should *test* against multiple versions, but your use case argues against specifying a hard-coded Ruby version as a dependency in your source tree. I provide a more expansive explanation and several different alternatives below.

Comment: ^^ This. There's a difference between "an application that needs to run with multiple versions" (what you asked) and "a library that needs to work as a plugin for other applications, that may be using different versions" (what you actually need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Gemfiles Declare Dependencies

A Gemfile declares a *dependency* on a Ruby version, with or without [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) constraints. It is not meant to control multiple build targets for your application. It simply enforces that the Ruby version available to your app/gem is whatever you've defined. For example:

```
# Will fail if run with a different RUBY_VERSION.
ruby '2.2.4'

# Allows RUBY_VERSION >= 2.2.4, but <= 2.3.
ruby '~> 2.2.4'

# Allows either Ruby 2.2.4+ or 2.5.5+, with
# a minimum (but no maximum) patch version.
ruby '~> 2.2.4', '~> 2.5.5'
```

However, it won't install a given Ruby, nor do anything other than raise an error and a non-zero exit status when running `bundler install`. You need to take a different approach to test multiple targets.

### Changing Build Targets with Continuous Integration (CI) Tools

If you're using an external CI like TravisCI, you can create a [build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/) that targets multiple Ruby versions to test against. Whether you remove the Ruby version constraint altogether, or specify a supported range, is up to you. Leveraging your CI tool to build against the versions of Ruby you plan to support is really the best approach, though, whether or not you constrain your Ruby runtime in a Gemfile.

For example, you might use a matrix in your [travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/) like so:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.4
  - 2.5.5
```

### Switching Gemfiles

If you insist on doing it the way you're doing it, with a singular Ruby version allowed in your Gemfile, then you might consider having two separate gemfiles with different names in your source tree, such as Gemfile-2.2.4 and Gemfile-2.5.5. You can then specify which Gemfile to use with [Bundler's `--gemfile` flag](https://bundler.io/v2.1/man/bundle-install.1.html) , or by symlinking a custom Gemfile to the canonical `Gemfile` for your project.

Here are some examples to consider:

```sh
# Resolve against a specific Gemfile with
# hard-coded Ruby version.

$ ls Gemfile*
Gemfile-2.2.4  Gemfile-2.5.5

$ bundle install --gemfile="Gemfile-2.2.4"
```

```sh
# Resolve against whatever custom file is
# symlinked to your ./Gemfile.

$ ln -sf Gemfile{-2.5.5,}

$ ls -F Gemfile*
Gemfile@       Gemfile-2.2.4  Gemfile-2.5.5

$ bundle install
```

Both approaches work, but the former is more flexible at the cost of needing to specify your chosen Gemfile each time, while the latter can help when you have a development/testing workflow that doesn't support Bundler's `--gemfile` flag.

### Changing Rubies with Ruby Managers

If you have multiple Ruby versions in development, best practice is to use a version manager such as rvm, rbenv, or chruby. You can use your version manager to change rubies back and forth manually as needed.

You might also check whether your version manager supports auto-switching on `.ruby-version` or other configuration files. You'd still have to update that file each time you want to build or test against a different Ruby, but you wouldn't have to keep changing your Gemfile contents, re-pointing the Gemfile symlink, or updating a flag on each call to Bundler.

Whether or not any given approach is better than others will depend on your workflow. No technical solution will fit all circumstances, so your mileage may legitimately vary.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I think I will try with the multiple gemfiles.